# Javascript HTML5 programing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a javascript project and need some help. Im trying to create a Bubble Buster game similar to the pong game but with many bubbles. I'm trying to create falling bubbles on my screen(about 100 count) in random colors and that drop from random points on the screen. Heres what I have, what am I doing wrong?

```
var canvasColor;
var x,y,radius,color;
var x=50, y=30
var bubbles=[];
var counter;

function startGame()
{
    var r,g,b;
    var canvas, pen;
    //Initialize
    canvasColor = '#EAEDDC';
    x = 10;
    y = 10;
    radius = 10;
    clearScreen();
    setInterval('drawForever()',50);

    //make bubble appear randomly
    x=Math.floor(Math.random()*450)

    //Set up a random color
    r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    pen.fillStyle='rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
    pen.fill();

            while (counter <100)
            {
                bubbles[counter]  = new Bubble(x,y,radius,color);
                counter+=1;
            }
}

function bubbles (x,y,radius,color)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.radius=radius;
    this.color=color;
}

function drawForever()
{
    var canvas, pen;

    clearScreen();

        while (counter <100)
        {
            pen.fillstyle(bubbles[counter].color);
            pen.beginPath();
            pen.arc(bubbles[counter].x,
                            bubbles[counter].y,
                            bubbles[counter].radius,
                            0,
                            2*Math.PI);
            pen.fill();

            bubbles[counter].y+=2;
            counter +=1;
        }
}


function drawCircle()
{
    var canvas, pen;

    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    pen = canvas.getContext('2d');


    pen.fillStyle = '#b3ffff';
    pen.beginPath();
    pen.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
    pen.fill();

}

function clearScreen()
{
    var canvas, pen;

    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    pen = canvas.getContext('2d');
    pen.fillStyle = canvasColor;
    pen.fillRect(0,0,450,300);

}
function drawShape()
{
    var canvas, pen;

    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    pen = canvas.getContext('2d');


    //Draw circle
    pen.fillStyle = '#b3ffff';
    pen.beginPath();
    pen.arc(50,50,25,0,2*Math.PI); //x,y,radius,startangle,endangle
    pen.fill();

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking, make sure to isolate a question so that others with the same issue can benefit from finding answers. Posting your code without knowing what is wrong is generally frowned upon and won't get you many answers. For starters, edit your question to add what works and what doesn't, and any error messages that might show up in the brower's console.

Answer (score 0):

In your start game variable you did not define canvas and pen.
this should be the correct code.

```
function startGame()
{
    var r,g,b;
    var canvas, pen;

    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    pen = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //Initialize
    canvasColor = '#EAEDDC';
    x = 10;
    y = 10;
    radius = 10;
    clearScreen();
    setInterval('drawForever()',50);

    //make bubble appear randomly
    x=Math.floor(Math.random()*450)

    //Set up a random color
    r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    pen.fillStyle='rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
    pen.fill();

            while (counter <100)
            {
                bubbles[counter]  = new Bubble(x,y,radius,color);
                counter+=1;
            }
}
```